Elementary symmetric polynomials can be expressed in terms of Newton sum.
I am reading Shavalievich's Basic Algebraic Geometry. In proposition A6, he mentioned a fact that every elementary symmetric polynomial can be expressed in terms of Newton polynomials (in any field $F$).
I am trying to inductively prove this using Newton identites:
$$ \begin{cases}
k\sigma_k+ &\sum\limits_{i=0}^{k-1} \sigma_i s_{k-i}=0 \qquad &k\leqslant n\\
&\sum\limits_{i=0}^n \sigma_i s_{k-i}=0 \qquad & k>n
\end{cases}$$
But when $\mathrm{char}(F)\mid k$, It seems that the induction cannot work anymore.
So how can we prove this fact? Any hints/ solutions are welcomed. Thanks!
Edit: As @Jean pointed out, here we should prove this under the assumptions:
$\sigma_i=\sigma_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the elementary symmetric polynomial, $s_i=s_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ is the Newton polynomial, and $\mathrm{char}(F)\nmid n$. (Even in this case, the induction seemingly cannot work...)

From the third edition of Shavalievich's Basic Algebraic Geometry, in proposition A.6 there is this hypothesis : "Assume that the order $n$ of $G$ is not divisible by char $k$". Furthermore, I do not believe that the result holds without this hypothesis.

@Jean Thanks for pointing this out. But I think there is still something wrong...

The fact is false in fields of positive characteristic: Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $2$. Then
$$
p_2=\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2 = \left( \sum_{k=1}^n x_k \right)^2 = p_1^2
$$
where $p_j$ is the power sum symmetric polynomial of degree $j$ in $n$ indeterminates. Take $n=2$. Then the symmetric polynomial $e_2=x_1x_2$ does not belong to the polynomial ring $k[p_1,p_2]=k[p_1]$.
ADDED: I have seen the proof you mention in the book and I agree with you that it must be rectified. There is this paper where the failure of Newton polynomials to generate the algebra of symmetric functions in arbitrary characteristic is explored. Nevertheless, Proposition A6 is still true, actually no condition on the characteristic is needed. You can take a look at Benson's Polynomial Invariants of Finite Groups, Theorem 1.3.1, where a very elegant proof is given. Also, this is an exercise in Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra with a view towards Algebraic Geometry (Exercises 13.2, 13.3 and Theorem 13.17).
Now, I believe that the reasoning behind the proof presented in Shavarevich's book is to provide an explicit set of generators for $A^G$. Actually the same proof can be found in Cox, Little, O'Shea's Ideals, Varieties and Algorithms (Theorem 5 in Chapter 7), where they explicitely state that they are working in a field of characteristic zero (but they work in the case of a finite matrix group).

Thank you! I think a similar argument works if we take n＝3 and consider the elementary symmetric polynomial of degree 2. So it seems that the original proof needs to be recitified.

@Zoudelong I added some stuff according to your comment and edit

Many thanks to your detailed answer! I  will take a closer look at them.
